# Finding a URL on a page

Tags: javascript, html

First of all I would like to say that my knowledge on HTML and all that programming stuff is very little but my work involves finding out certain aspects of a source code like Link URLs to improve the process i work on.

I have been facing an issue since a few days though as one of the sites am trying to retrieve a certain link from has been written in a different language than HTML i think. It's link ends with .aspx and never changes even when I navigate it's pages.

I tried to check the page's source code from where i need to find this one particular URL but it is written in javascript and i have no idea about reading it. I tried googling to find a solution but didnt come across anything helpful or maybe I just was not able to understand because like I said I hardly have any knowledge about programming.

Anyway, I have figured out where the link is on the page but I want someone to tell me how to go about to find out what URL is behind it. It looks like this in the source code :

```
</div> -->
    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidateButton" value="View Image" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidateButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ValidateButton" /><br />
</div>
```

The whole thing from where my point of interest on the page starts from looks like this but there's no captcha entering involved. You just click the button and it downloads the file:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageLink"><h4>[Image]</h4></a> </DIV>
                        <DIV align="center"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImageInfo">- File Size: 582KB | Pages: 1 -</span> </DIV><BR />
                        <DIV align="left"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ErrorMessage"></span> </DIV>
                        <DIV align="left"><span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_documentError"></span> </DIV>

                                <div align=center>
                                    <!-- <div id="CaptchaDiv">
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = {
            theme : 'clean',
            tabindex : 0
        };

</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfZzsMSAAAAAD2h79x90-FvI0AtkBatVFqydtgE">

</script><noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfZzsMSAAAAAD2h79x90-FvI0AtkBatVFqydtgE" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0">

        </iframe><br /><textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea><input name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" type="hidden" />
</noscript>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidateButton" value="View Image" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ValidateButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ValidateButton" /><br />
                                </div>
```

Comment: Your `div` tags do not match up. Did you mean to put `<div>` in place of `</div> -->`?

Comment: .aspx is ASP.net..it is a server side language just like php and the server parse/hide aspx source code thats why you can only see javascript codes.

Comment: What do you want to do with that URL?

Comment: So, is there no way to find out what link is being used behind that button?

Comment: It is used for some confidential downloads.

Comment: 1. Why do a job when you have no idea what to do?
2. Ever heard of copyright infringement?
3. What's the incentive? A warm fuzzy feeling inside?

Comment: This is not the only job i do at work. I take care of various things. I am just asking a help for this issue because it will speed up my work. What about Copyright infringement? I have proper access to the sites i work with. I know what i am doing.

Comment: Um...if you have proper access...um....wouldn't you already have the source?

Comment: I have access to the downloads. But i everytime i need a file i need to search for it on the portal. What i am trying to do with this method is, finding the URL of one of the downloads so that all i have to do is change it in a minor way (the files are named in a serial way) to acquire direct download links for my files.

Comment: After you click the button, the form does a postback (it submits the form, possibly asynchronously - my aspx knowledge is getting a bit fuzzy). This triggers some server-side code, which in turn produces the download. From this page it is not possible (or very complicated) to find the link to the file using Javascript.
My best guess is that you need to locate the url of the file in your browser and save it somewhere, then change that link - as you said, the files are named in a serial way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe those code will help to u:

```
var urlexp = new RegExp('(http|ftp|https)://[a-z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-z0-9\-_]+)+([a-z0-9\-\.,@\?^=%&;:/~\+#]*[a-z0-9\-@\?^=%&;/~\+#])?', 'i');
var result = urlexp.exec(document.body.innerHTML);
```

the `result` is array including matched urls.

Comment: Can you please tell how do i use this?

Comment: var result = urlexp.exec(document.body.innerHTML);

Comment: Sorry, I think u should be learning some basic of javascript.